# Sharing photos with friends using Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I am about to join Dropbox and would like to create a folder of photos to share with some friends, so have a couple of questions:

1. Do they have to be members of Dropbox if they want to download any photos from the folder?
2. Would they be able to upload their own photos onto the folder whether they were members or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. Depending on how you set the preferences. By default - no, but there are ways to circumvent that.